# In aws, i wanna change root volume naming convention /dev/sda1 to /opt/cong is it possible or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In aws, i wanna change root volume naming convention "/dev/sda1" to "/opt/cong" is it possible or not

Answer (score 0):

no, The root volume is reserved by Amazon and cannot be changed, you can read more http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html

- For Paravirtual instances, the root volume will be `/dev/sda1`
- For HVM instances, the root volume will be either  `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/xvda`

[image]